# Word Error Rate weights

Tags: speech-recognition

Usually ASR systems are evaluated using WER ([word error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_error_rate)), which summarizes 3 types of changes when calculating the edit distance: insertions, deletions and substitutions. According to the wikipedia page, there are two versions:

A. each type is given the same score: 1, 1, 1 (S, D, I)

B. Hunt's version: 1, 0.5, 0.5

I've noticed that [sclite](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/docs/sctk-1.2/sclite.htm) has it's own weights

C. sclite: 4, 3, 3

What are the use cases for each weighting scheme? My goal is to compare different speech recognition APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The various weighting systems are a domain-speific attempt to adapt the raw edit distance metric into something more "perceptual". The needs & error tolerances for one domain, say large vocab open speech, may be different from the command-and-control, "assistant" systems.

Humans differentially weigh different types of ASR errors and are less forgiving with errors (like say insertions) which may distort the meaning of the transcription.

Have a look at this paper: [Predicting Human Perceived Accuracy of ASR Systems](http://web2-clone.research.att.com/export/sites/att_labs/techdocs/TD_100444.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting paper, I wonder what were their final weights. My goal is to compare APIs for conversations between people (i.e, open with a large vocabulary).